# Как в Котлине уменьшить количество цифр после точки?

Tags: kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В результате вычислений получается число 29.985000000000003, но нужно, что бы было число 29.985
Как заставить функцию вернуть Dooble где было бы только 3 знака после точки? Округление не годится, нужно именно отрезать лишние цифры.

Comment: Есть ограничения на представление чисел с плавающей точкой. Не все десятичные дроби можно представить точно в типе double. Для некоторых будет ошибка в представлении. Т.е. вы не можете изменить, значение хранящегося числа, так как 29.985 в принципе нельзя точно в виде double хранить. Единственное что вы можете, это выводит числа с точностью до какого-то знака, а это будет округление либо обрезание.

Comment: Вот нашёл такое на просторах и это помогло   val number:Double = 0.0449999
val number3digits:Double = Math.round(number * 1000.0) / 1000.0
val number2digits:Double = Math.round(number3digits * 100.0) / 100.0
val solution:Double = Math.round(number2digits * 10.0) / 10.0

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что округление не годится? Отбрасывая значащие разряды вы вносите ошибку в ответ.

Comment: Более того, якобы *решение* которое вы нашли, таки использует округление.

Comment: Годится, т.к. задача прошла проверку

Answer (score 3):

Используйте форматирование [Java String format()](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/library/string/format):

```
val x = 29.985000000000003

println( String.format("%.3f", x) )  // output: 29.985
```

Цифра поле точки указывает, сколько знаков после запятой будет напечатано. При этом, используется **округление** числа до заданной точности.

Comment: Еще можно так: `println("%.3f".format(x))`

Answer (score 1):

без округления, просто отбрасывает ненужные знаки после запятой:

```
val value = 12.345678
val d1 = floor(value * 10.0) / 10.0 // 12.3
val d2 = floor(value * 100.0) / 100.0 // 12.34
val d3 = floor(value * 1000.0) / 1000.0 // 12.345
val d3 = floor(value * 10000.0) / 10000.0 // 12.3456
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте простую математику!)

```
var x = 29.98642
x = (x * 100).roundToInt() / 100.0 // делить надо обязательно на тип Double 
 // 29.99
```

метод `roundToInt()` не просто обрезает, но еще и округляет, согласно правилам.